# Is there a possibility to place Canvas-objects in Tkinter-grids

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, python-3.8

Since you can create images, rectangles, lines and so on in the Tkinter-Canvas, I wonder if there is any possibility to place an image in a grid.

What I tried:

```py
from tkinter import *
w = Tk()

background = Canvas(w, highlightthickness = 0)
for r in range(10):
    ntexture = PhotoImage(PATH)
    background.create_image(image = ntexture, row = r, column = 2)

background.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
w.mainloop()
```

When I execute it, there is an IndexError.

The Problem:
There is are no attributes for row or column.

Do you know how to get the coordinates of rows/columnes or how to do it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use grid coordinates you need to use the .grid() method, rather than .pack().

In your case something like

```
bg = background.create_image(image = ntexture)
bg.grid(row = r, column = 2)
```